# How do I get the current editor from a QTableView?

Tags: qt

Is there a way of getting the editor (a QLineEdit instance) while the editing is in progress?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The delegate creates the editing widget, but does not store it and the view does not give access to it (presumably because it is not persistent).

So you will have to subclass `QStyledItemDelegate` and reimplement `createEditor(QWidget*, const QStyleOptionViewItem&, const QModelIndex&) const` to store a copy of the returned pointer.  Then you can provide access to the editor through the delegate.

AFAIK you cannot create multiple editors at once in a single view, and delegate sharing across views is [discouraged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate), so holding the last created editor should be sufficient.  I would also create a private slot that nulls the pointer and connect it to the destroyed signal of the created editor - so you know it is always valid.

Comment: I had the same idea - but there's a bit of a problem: the method `createEditor(QWidget*, const QStyleOptionViewItem&, const QModelIndex&) const` is marked `const` - so you can't modify `this` object, which implies that you can't really store the pointer that is beeing returned . Or am I missing something?

Comment: The storage for the pointer can simply be marked as `mutable`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I found it while researching this exact question.

I solved it this way:

In `QStyledItemDelegate::createEditor`, I emit a `const` signal informing about an editor being created, with a pointer to the newly created editor. I connect this signal to my view, which does not store the pointer directly, but using a `QPointer`.

This way, one can easily check if there's an editor and one can also be sure one can use it without the danger of running into a segfault, because the `QPointer` will point to `nullptr` if the object it points to has been deleted meanwhile.

So one simply has to check for the `QPointer` pointing to `nullptr` (no editing going on) or not (in this case, it points to the currently active editor).